# google sheet -- protect sheet and unprotect all non-formulas within with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I'm new to Google Apps Script and trying to write a script to perform the following:

1. Protect Active sheet, then within a specified Range on that sheet:
2. Determine all "Formula cells/ranges" (and therefore the "non-Formula cells/ranges"), then
3. Unprotect the non-Formula Range[]

Here's what I'm currently working with  (pls refer to the section where I'm stuck)

```
function protectFormulas() {

// DEFINE WORKSHEET
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
// PROTECT ACTIVE SHEET
    var protection = ws.protect().setDescription('Protect Fomulas');
  
// Establish Range and Formulas within [currently my range is the entire sheet]
    var range = ws.getDataRange();
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();  
    
// *****THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK - how to determine the Range[] Array within "Formulas" ??  [aka ignore the notes]
    //var result = new Array(formulas.length)
    //for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
        //IF formulas [i] is blank
            //add formulas R1C1 to Result Array [how to?]
        //ELSE
            // do nothing
    //}
//  *****END OF WHERE I'M STUCK


// UNPROTECT select Ranges  
  var unprotected = ws.range;
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(result);

  }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

```
function protectFormulas() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let up = [];
  let protection=sh.protect();
  const range = sh.getDataRange();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  formulas.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c == '') {//if not a formula then add range to up
         up.push(sh.getRange(i+1,j+1));
      }
    });
  });
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(up);//unprotect ranges in up
}
```

Comment: Cooper you're a genius!!   Now rather than the ranges within "up" only becoming individual cells, is there any way to modify the loop to join any/all adjacent non-formula cells together? [to limit the #ranges within UP]

Comment: Also - is there any way to ask the user to select which "range" they wish to search/protect? [aka rather than the entire worksheet sh.getDataRange();]

Comment: First Question: Probably but I don't want to do it. Second Question: Ui().prompt()

Comment: Ok thx.  Can anyone else condense the range? (question 1)